# how marathon determine a service instance is ready to service

Tags: mesos, marathon

buddies

I am wondering how marathon get to know a serice instance is ready to service?

Is there any interface to customize the health check during the starting up of a instance?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the docs at

- https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/health-checks.html

You can implement a variety of checks, not only on http endpoints, but also tcp... For example, if you're starting a dockerized MySQL service, you could perform a health check on tcp port 3306 to verify that MySQL is actually started and reachable:

```
"healthChecks": [
    {
        "portIndex": 0,
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "intervalSeconds": 1,
        "timeoutSeconds": 2,
        "maxConsecutiveFailures": 5
    }
]
```

To be dynamic, the `portIndex` is important. So for example, you used bridged networking with Docker, and Marathon chooses the port automatically (and you only exposed on port), then the `portIndex` needs to be set to one.

Also, if you want immediate health check upon startup (i.e. the task should not be considered as `RUNNING` until everything's up), you'll need to omit the `gracePeriodSeconds` parameter.

Comment: What is the difference between `readinessChecks` and `healthChecks` ? => https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/readiness-checks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use healthcheck but there is also a readinessChecks.
https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/master/docs/docs/readiness-checks.md

There is also the minimumHealthCapacity in the upgrades strategy https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#upgrade-strategy